# How do I nest in my t2 timeline into my t1 timeline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I have a simple animation. At the end of the animation one of the objects opacity is supose to go from 100% to 0% and repeat. However its not working as exptected. I think i just need to nest the t2 timeline in t1 but everything i am trying isn't working.

I am very new to JS so any suggestion would be great!

Have a look at my Greensock Js

```
// Banner Animation
console.clear();
var wait = 100;



var tl = new TimelineMax();
var t2 = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

//drop in animation
tl

.from('#hl_E', 1.3, {top: -100, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}) 
.from('#hl_D2', 1.3, {top: -100, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=1.1') 
.from('#hl_M', 1.3, {top: -100, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.9')

.to('#hl_E', .3, {top: 20, left:-123, ease: Power2.easeOut}) 
.to('#hl_D2', .3, {top: 20, left:-43, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.3') 
.to('#hl_M', .3, {top: 20, left:-43, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.3')

.from('#hl_D1', .5, {left:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.2') 
.from('#hl_A', .5, {bottom:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5') 
.from('#hl_O', .5, {top:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5')
.from('#hl_D3', .5, {left:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5')
.from('#hl_Z', .5, {right:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5')
.from('#hl_--', .5, {top:-10, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5')
.from('#hl_-', .5, {left:-15, opacity: 0, ease: Power2.easeOut}, '-=.5')
.from('.logoGlow', 15.8, {opacity: 0, ease: Elastic.easeOut})

t2.to('.logoGlow', 1, {opacity: 0, yoyo:true})
.to('.logoGlow', 1, {opacity: 100, yoyo:true});
```

Html

```
<div id="hl_D1" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_E" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_A" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_D2" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_M" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_O" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_D3" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_Z" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_-" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div> 
<div id="hl_--" class="heroLogoAssets"> </div>
</div> <!-- END heroLogo-Wrap -->
<div class="logoGlow"><img src="img/enterLogobg.png" width="777" height="189" alt=""/></div>
<div id="heroLinks-Wrap">
```

Comment: And we are very new to *your* JS :) Please provide a sample of the HTML too!

Comment: Please provide more information. 1) What are you trying to accomplish? ; 2) What exactly seems to be the problem? (what is the result of your current code? | any console output?) ; 3) Could you provide a codepen? (they let you select TweenMax as a source) ; 4) HTML would also be appreciated.

Comment: I am just wondering how to nest the t2 inside of t1 so that t2 plays inside of t1. 

I can never get greensock to work in jsfiddle or codepen..

Comment: Added html to the post

Comment: @Portal_Zii : Added an anwer to the post. (I created the pen before I had your HTML so I made something up)

Answer (score 1):

I created a small [CodePen](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/KVrxax) for you.

Since you want the **whole** timeline `t2` to `repeat` and `yoyo` you can define that in the `constructor`:

```
var t2 = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1, yoyo:true});
```

Then you can just add the timeline `t2` to `t1`. `t2` will be **appended** to `t1` and start executing when the **original** `t1` finishes.

```
t1.add(t2);
```

(I say **original** because `t1` now contains `t2`)

**EDIT:**

If you want some time to pass between the **end** of the **original** `t1` and the **start** of `t2` you could alter the `position` of `t2` when adding it to `t1`:

```
t1.add(t2, '+=5');
```

Now `t2` will start 5 seconds after the **original** `t1` ends.

Comment: Dude you rock! This is very close to what I am trying to do. However. by nesting them I thought it would solve my problem of trying to get t2 to not play until after t1 but have t2 repeat forever. Any ideas?

Comment: After the original `t1` finishes `t2` does start and it repeats forever.

Comment: @Portal_Zii : If you are still having trouble it would be helpful if you posted your updated code :)